# router animations not preserving height while animating

Tags: css, angular, animation, router

in my angular project I added router animations and they work fine except for a major lag which in my view is caused by the viewport loosing it's `height: 100%` css setting durring the animation keyframes.

as a result it first starts by drawing a scrunched-down version of the current view to replace the current view, animate that switching to a scrunched up view of the component coming into view, then redraw the new view it just loaded with it's actual height value, and it tries to do all that within a couple milliseconds.

If the views each have a hard-coded height (for example : `height: 200px`, in which case it doesn't depend on the parent to know what it'll look like in the end.), then the animation doesn't lag because then it only has to draw the "sliding to right" frames of the view it currently has + the view it's loading.

so it's really the `height` property being lost that's causing the lag.

the thing is I need the 100% height as I use that to obtain a content that resizes dynamically if the content above the router-outlet changes size.

how do I get to keep both `height: 100%` and router-animations?

Comment: try  min-height: 100%

Comment: can you add a demo

Comment: @TaranjitKang not dynamic (100% is more than the height of my routed-content and the content above has a dynamic height so calc(100% - 150px) won't work either)

Comment: @Stavm short on time and coding my project a second time into stackblitz isn't something I can allot time for, so unfortunately maybe later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative sizes are not working well if there is other content like headers or footers. If the other content has a dynamic height, try the following in your router transition:

`style({ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', top: '10%', bottom: '0' })`

That way the animation should work without any lag.

Comment: where should that go? the div of router outlet? style that is part of the animation declaration? where?

Comment: putting that in the animation declaration (`transition(
      ':enter', [
        style({position: 'absolute', width: '100%', top: '190px', bottom: '0', opacity: 0}),`) changed nothing :(

Comment: this is so clever but indeed the `style` var in the transition declaration is not only your means to animate but also an opportunity to set the style for a "phantom div" that is otherwise inaccessible. testing more thoroughly  tomorrow, if tomorrow there is no drawback to this method I'll allot you the point.